# What is the rank structure of Imperial Stormtroopers?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

There must be several levels. In the U.S. Army there is the private (new recruit) all the way to General.

What is the rank structure of Imperial Stormtroopers?

Comment: They're ranked in order of competence in shooting. They're **all** Private 1st Class.

Comment: @Richard joke right? There must be ranks.

Comment: The boring version is here: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rank_insignia_of_the_Galactic_Empire/old_version

Comment: What kind of Stormtroopers are you referring to? There are Imperial and First Order Stormtroopers; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112582/what-do-different-colors-of-stormtrooper-pauldrons-indicate

Comment: Now write a self-answer and you get both sets up upvotes, those from the question *and* those from your answer.

Comment: @Richard thanks, didn't know that, I did it.

Comment: "Dead" and "Will be dead soon".

Comment: @WadCheber lol.

Answer (score 4):

For the boring version go to here [to Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rank_insignia_of_the_Galactic_Empire/old_version):

> **Stormtroopers apparently use the same rank system as the Imperial
>   Army, but rarely wear any type of outward insignia.** It is mentioned
>   that Stormtroopers most likely have an identification scanner, built
>   into their helmets, which can determine the rank and seniority of
>   other stormtroopers. This does not explain, however, the colored
>   shoulder pads used by Stormtroopers on Tatooine. Also, in the Battle
>   of Hoth, a stormtrooper is seen wearing the insignia of an Army
>   Captain on his armor. It is assumed that such insignia display is for
>   the benefit of non-stormtrooper personnel.
>
> In the higher ranks of the Stormtroopers, it can be reasonably assumed
>   that the senior Stormtrooper officers do not wear the Battle Armor on
>   a regular basis, thus a different uniform, for the more casual
>   "office" setting, would most likely be worn. This explains a number of
>   Imperial officers, seen in the feature films directing groups of
>   Stormtroopers, who appear to be wearing solid black uniforms with rank
>   badges. Such personnel are most likely Stormtrooper commanders whose
>   daily duties do not necessitate the regular wearing of battle armor.

If you click on the links you will see additional examples of people both non-canon (EU) and in-canon in each rank.

Some sample information includes:

1. Navy Rank
2. Army Rank
3. Version 1
4. Version 2

Comment: Don't forget to add in some quotes. Link-only answers are frowned on because if the link dies, the answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Based on some books like the Star Wars visual dictionary, battlefront and other sources here is my interpretation of the Stormtrooper Pauldron ranks. Seems to make sense to me.

Comment: Red was used as Commander in Battlefront. As the other comments mention commanders seemed to not usually be in the white armor. So could explain the rare appearances of the red pauldron in the films, in the instance a commander wasn't in the officer uniform and was wearing the white armor you might see the red pauldron.

Answer (score 0):

So the Storm Trooper Corps Rank are and pauldron colors are:

- Cadet
- Private
- Lance Corporal, Black pauldron.
- Corporal, Grey pauldron.
- Sergeant, White pauldron.
- Staff Sergeant, Orange pauldron.
- Master Sergeant, Red pauldron.

Officer ranks of the storm Trooper corps:

- Officer Cadet
- Lieutenant
- Captain
- Major
- Colonel
- Commander

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What is the source of the image and your information?  Attribution is an important part of writing a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a website containing ranks for different divisions in the Galactic Empire, pretty sure it's Legends based though. It was called galacticempire.org/ranks or something along those lines. I don't have a picture since the website no longer exists due to the administrator of the site shutting it down, but I can type out a list:
(There was nothing showing for E0, N0, N2, N3, O0, O2, O4, O6, O8, CO0, CO2, CO4, and CO5, so I inferred what they might be)

#### Key

- **E**: Enlisted
- **N**: Non-Commissioned Officer
- **O**: Officer
- **CO**: Command Officer

#### List

- **E0**: Cadet
- **E1**: Apprentice Trooper
- **E2**: Trooper
- **E3**: Corporal
- **E4**: Sergeant
- **E5**: Senior Sergeant
- **E6**: Chief
- **N0**: Junior Officer Cadet
- **N1**: Officer Cadet
- **N2**: Warrant Officer
- **N3**: Chief Warrant Officer
- **O0**: Senior Officer Cadet
- **O1**: Lieutenant
- **O2**: First Lieutenant
- **O3**: Captain
- **O4**: Major
- **O5**: Field Commander
- **O6**: Auxiliary Command
- **O7**: Line Commander
- **O8**: Operational Command
- **CO0**: Command Cadet
- **CO1**: Major Commander
- **CO2**: Administrative Command
- **CO3**: General
- **CO4**: Corps Command
- **CO5**: Storm Corps Brigadier

Comment: Adding a source, be it canon or Legends, would greatly improve this answer. If you don't know the source, you might try clicking on the '[Ask Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)' button at the top of the page in order to post your own question seeking the source of this information. And if someone provides the correct source, you could then edit this answer to cite it.

Comment: Neither of those ones are, but they have similar content. As I said the website was shut down. There's a video on YouTube that shows the website: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhe7L5laGzc

Answer (score -5):

First Order Stormtrooper squad leaders were Sergeant Stormtroopers within the First Order. Squad leaders (Sergeants) were responsible for all

- Training,
- Discipline,
- Mentoring and
- Conducted tactical planning and execution of orders in conjunction with the platoon leader at squad level.

They would lead teams of seven Troopers and one Corporal. The Corporal acted as the Sergeant's assistant squad leader and conducted all administration within the squad.

The squad consisted of two fire teams - Alpha and Bravo. In a flanking attack, Alpha the (Sergeant and four other troopers) would conduct the assault on the objective while the Bravo Team - the Corporal, 2 Gunner Troopers armed with FWMB-10 repeating blasters and a Marksman armed with a F-11D enhanced scope - would provide fire support (base of fire) to the assaulting team.

A Stormtrooper platoon consisted of:

- A Lieutenant (Platoon Leader),
- Sergeant Major (Platoon Sergeant),
- 1 Trooper (platoon signaller),
- 4 Sergeants (squad leaders),
- 4 Corporals (assistant squad leaders) and
- 28 Troopers.

Comment: Interesting, where is this information from?

Comment: This is just my own take on the function of a squad and the squad leaders role within it. I'm hoping it will catch on in the franchise.

Comment: I am still confused tho. It states a squad leader wears a white Pauldon and a sergeant wears a black Pauldon. Firstly, "squad leader is a position/function not a rank. Secondly, what is the function/role/ duties/ command of a Sergeant???