# When did the coloured shoulder pauldrons on stormtroopers first appear?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, stormtroopers, clothing

I was watching *A New Hope* on Netflix, when I noticed that in the scene with the stormtrooper riding a dewback, we see some of the other stormtroopers wearing [the coloured shoulder pauldrons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112582/19561) that signify their rank.

I don't recall having seen them before, so when (out of universe) were these added?

I *thought* they were a new invention for *The Force Awakens*.

Comment: Wookieepedia says that *A New Hope* is their first appearance (presumably in a released movie). I’ll have to see if Lucas edited them it. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those shoulder pads have been there since day one. So to speak. ;-)

[image: A behind the scenes picture. Notice the shoulder pad.]
**A behind the scenes picture. Notice the shoulder pad.**

Answer (score 12):

The first work that they appeared, by order of release, was *A New Hope*. Here they are in the famous “these aren’t the droids you’re looking for” scene, from a version of *Star Wars* that comes from the original prints.

[image]

Here is a version from a later Blu-Ray edition of *A New Hope*:

[image]

**They also were seen in many other works before *The Force Awakens*.** For example, Clone Troopers in the *Clone Wars* series wore pauldrons.

[image]

**So they definitely weren’t created specifically for *The Force Awakens*.**

Comment: The uppoermost image appears to be from the blu-ray release, hence the letterboxing to make it widescreen

Comment: @Valorum - Sure, because the old versions are grainy. But they are there in the originals.

Comment: But the OP was looking for proof-positive that they were in an earlier version.

Comment: @Valorum - Fine, let me find a picture then.

Comment: @Valorum - I’m seeing if I can find a clip from the Silver Screen Edition, made from an original film print.

Comment: @Valorum - I found a Silver Screen Edition clip. This is from the original 35 mm film.

Comment: Much better :-)

Answer (score 5):

They were seen in the original 1977 theatrical release.

[image]

Comment: I don't know how I could've missed them.

Comment: @SQB - I like the new blu-ray quality, but I detest the additional crap that Lucas has shoved into the frame.

Comment: Jabba, you're a wonderful human being -- solo

Comment: @Valorum: Look for Harmy's Despecialized Edition... HD quality, original 1977's frames.